# Retrieve SugarCRM employee emails

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

I'm writing some code for sugarCRM, and I'd like to notify employees via email. I'm using the active record model to get employees, but their emails are nowhere to be found.

`$employees = BeanFactory::getBean('Employees')->get_full_list();`

How do I get the active employee emails via this interface? I need to pluck them out of the records and add them to the email I'm sending out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save user's email address use this:

```
$sea = new SugarEmailAddress;
$sea->addAddress($bean->email1, true);
$sea->save($newUser->id, "Users");
```

To retrieve primary email address use this:

```
$primary_email=$user->emailAddress->getPrimaryAddress($user);
```

Hope this will help you... :)

Checkout this for more:
[SugarCRM Developer](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/03/08/howto-add-and-retrieve-email-addresses-in-a-module-thru-code/)

Comment: Beautiful! Now that we're back in the ORM world, we can use objects instead of writing a bunch of custom queries!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this situation but I came up with the below solution. Hope it works for you. Cheers!!

```
<?php

$userId=array('2132131312323232','323232323232323'); //array of users id's
foreach($userId as $key => $val) {
 $email_query = "select E.email_address from email_addr_bean_rel EB inner join email_addresses E on EB.email_address_id = E.id WHERE EB.bean_id='".$val."' and E.deleted = 0"; 
 // Your implementation
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing sAcH and this [the schema documentation](http://apidocs.sugarcrm.com/schema/6.5.23/ce/tables/email_addr_bean_rel.html), I ended up writing the query below. It can probably be cleaned up a lot, but it functions and that's what I care about right now.

It returns the primary email of all active, non-deleted employees, effectively making an email list for your active users:

```
select e.email_address
from email_addr_bean_rel eb
    inner join email_addresses e
    on eb.email_address_id = e.id
where eb.bean_id in
    (select id
        from users
        where deleted = 0 and employee_status = 'Active')
    and e.deleted = 0 and eb.primary_address = 1
    and eb.deleted = 0 and eb.bean_module = 'Users'
```

Important to note, is that there are two fields where a user can be active: status and employee_status. This checks the latter; just note that there are two 'status' fields, not one!